# parseInt alternative which returns NaN when string does not really contain real integer

Tags: javascript

In this case, parseInt return `12`:

`"12.5 Im the king of the world"`

Is there a native function of JavaScript to check the string and return NaN if the string does not really represent an integer?

Comment: Other methods like `Number("...")` or `+"..."` are stricter but not exactly what you want. You'll probably have to craft a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` unary operator, which does the same thing as the Number constructor, and then check explicitly to see if the result is an integer:

```
var str = "12.5 whatever";
var int = +str;
if (isNaN(int) || Math.floor(int) !== int)
  // not an integer
else
  // an integer
```

That will let you determine if the original string has garbage in it, but also check whether the string represented an integer as opposed to a number with a fractional part.

Comment: Not necessarily bad, but take into account that `"12e9"` or `"   12     \t\n"` count as integers here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález well, they are in fact integers. Ignoring white space is a weird thing that JavaScript does, for probably historical reasons.

Comment: It also recognizes `"+Infinity"`, also a little weird. The implications of that are up to the OP to handle I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the + operator is what you're looking for:

```
let foo = "12.5 Im the king of the world";
let bar = parseInt(foo);
let baz = +foo;
console.log(bar, typeof bar);
console.log(baz, typeof baz);
```

This will return:

```
12 'number'
NaN 'number'
```